# How to *efficiently* monitor a webpage modified with javascript?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pyqt4, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor an element on a website that's generated via javascript.  The problem of downloading a javascript modified page has been handled before, I borrowed the following code that solves the problem with PyQt.

But when I set this code to run every 20 seconds, my network traffic averages 70KB/s down 5 KB/s up.   The actual page saved is only 80KB, but is javascript heavy.

6GB a day is not reasonable, my ISP has data limits and I already toe the line.

Is there a way to modify this code so that, for example, it only executes the javascript that corresponds to a specific element on the page?  If so, how would I go about figuring out what I need to execute?  And would that have a significant effect on the network traffic I'm seeing?

Alternately, how SHOULD I be doing this?  I considered making a chrome extension, as Chrome would already be handling the javascript for me, but then I have to figure out how to integrate it with the rest of my project, and that's brand new territory for me.  If there's a better way I'd rather do that.

```
#Borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161737/cannot-add-custom-request-headers-in-pyqt4
#which is borrowed from http://blog.motane.lu/2009/07/07/downloading-a-pages-content-with-python-and-webkit/

import sys, signal
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply


cookie = ''#snipped, the cookie I have to send is about as long as this bit of code...

class MyNetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self, url):
            QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)
            request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url))
            self.reply = self.get(request)

    def createRequest(self, operation, request, data):
            request.setRawHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
            request.setRawHeader("Cookie",cookie);
            return QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest( self, operation, request, data )

class Crawler( QWebPage ):
        def __init__(self, url, file):
                QWebPage.__init__( self )
                self._url = url
                self._file = file
                self.manager = MyNetworkAccessManager(url)
                self.setNetworkAccessManager(self.manager)

        def crawl( self ):
                signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL )
                self.loadFinished.connect(self._finished_loading)
                self.mainFrame().load( QUrl( self._url ) )

        def _finished_loading( self, result ):
                file = open( self._file, 'w' )
                file.write( self.mainFrame().toHtml() )
                file.close()
                exit(0)

def main(url,file):
        app = QApplication([url,file])
        crawler = Crawler(url, file)
        crawler.crawl()
        sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: What is your objective here? What metric(s) are your trying to gather?

Comment: There is a text string on the webpage that changes periodically between four different strings, I want to report to the rest of my program when it changes and which of the four strings it is.

Comment: To be clear, are you effectively wanting to capture a website state (as modified by its JavaScript) every 20 seconds? That's bound to create a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

First, be clear about your motivation here. Something is changing every 20 seconds and you want to tell the server when one field changes. So

1). Do you need to send the whole page or just the contents of one field. I'm not clear what you are currently doing, but if you are sending 80k every 20 seconds this seems like overkill.

2). Does the server need to know immediately? What are the consequences of sending the state every minute rather than every 20 seconds. You miss some changes, but does that matter?

You haven't really told what you're doing or why, so we can't comment on that.

My first thought is that if the server just wants to know about one field then make an ajax call with just the payload you care about. To me more efficient send a summary every few minutes. One composite record is much cheaper than several small records.